# How does one use or get started with ...theme.mixins.toolbar in Material-ui?

Tags: material-ui

I cannot find any documentation for ...theme.mixins.toolbar in the material-ui docs. What does this do? How do I change or use it?

[image]

Answer (score 27):

It simply adds a minimum height to an element. It's useful when you use the AppBar with a content section below, and you want to add a spacer at the top of your content so it doesn't disappear under the AppBar, for example.

I can't find specific documentation on it, but there are examples of it being used in the Material-UI [layout examples](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/page-layout-examples/) and I believe it might be created by [this function](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createMixins.js).

More specifically, it's used in the [Dashboard example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/page-layout-examples/dashboard/Dashboard.js):

```
toolbarIcon: {
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  padding: '0 8px',
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
},
```

This would result in something like:

```
toolbarIcon: {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justifyContent: flex-end;
  padding: 0 8px;
  min-height: 64px;
}
```

Comment: Irritating that this extremely common requirement isn't included directly in the [AppBar documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/)...

Comment: how is min-height gonna help push it out of under appbar?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer check out https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#ResponsiveDrawer.js this link. It uses <div className={classes.toolbar} /> in the main tag, so this div occupies a min-height hence tags after it are displayed normally, i.e. looks as if they start after app bar. If removed, our real content will be obscured partly by the app bar.

Comment: @JeremyField, now it is: https://mui.com/components/app-bar/#fixed-placement

Answer (score 8):

There is global default theme. Specifically the theme.mixin.toolbar property on the object adds a min height.

```
theme:
 breakpoints: Object
  direction: "ltr"
 mixins: Object
  gutters: f gutters()
  toolbar: Object
   minHeight: 56
   @media (min-width:0px) and (orientation: landscape): Object
   @media (min-width:600px): Object
```

From the site:

> Tip: you can play with the documentation theme object in your console,
>   as the theme variable is exposed on all the documentation pages.
>   Please note that the documentation site is using a custom theme.
>
> If you want to learn more about how the theme is assembled, take a
>   look at [material-ui/style/createMuiTheme.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createMuiTheme.js), and the related imports
>   which createMuiTheme uses.

Here is the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/)

Comment: Using the dense variant of the toolbar - `<Toolbar variant="dense" />` changes the min height - But I can't find this in the theme object/can't see how this works. 

Do you know how to access the dense variant size programatically?