# Which height is used for AppBar, Toolbar in Material-UI?

Tags: css, material-ui

I need to know exactly which height for this is used:

```
<AppBar position="static">
  <Toolbar>
```

because later in an other component I have the following calculation. Now I assume it is 64px, but seems on mobile it is smaller.

```
return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          maxWidth: `calc(calc((100vmin - 64px) * ${this.state.aspectRatio})+200px)`
        }}
```

https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Answer (score 1):

The heights are listed in the [default theme](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/#default-theme) under mixins:
[image]

Comment: Hi! Means with different orientation height is different? :) I guess 48px is for landscape and 64px is for portrait. What do you think when 56px is applied?

Comment: It also depends on the device screen size: Mobile vs Desktop e.g., So mobile will probably get 48 px, tablets 56 and desktops 64.

Comment: My experience height is 64px on desktop and mobil landscape, but on mobil portrait it is 70px. I tested on iPhone 6s.

Comment: How do I get the current value in my code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53329367/11599909